# Problem when getting started on Supabase's Flutter Google Auth, google pages redirects back to login_page

Tags: google-oauth, supabase-flutter

I have been trying to get this done for a long time now. It's not the common 'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.googleusercontent.apps.account_id' problem.

I have followed this tutorial (a couple of times):

https://supabase.com/blog/flutter-authentication

The problem is the following:

When I open the app (with android studio) and click on the  Google login button i get redirected correctly and a browser lets me choose my google account, up to here everything its as it should. Then when i get rediected to the app, I go back to the login page without being able to do anything (Also user does not get added on supabase auth users table).

I have tried everything and also even downloaded some github repositories examples (https://github.com/supabase/supabase/tree/master/examples/auth/flutter-native-google-auth) to try and get it to work from someones else code.

This are the steps I have tried a lot of times:

I create the files login_screen.dart, profile_screen.dart and edit main.dart to what the tutorial says..

Then I change:

-supabase url and anonkey in main.dart

-Platform.isIOS ? 'iosaccount_id.apps.googleusercontent.com' : 'android_account_id.apps.googleusercontent.com'; in login_screen.dart

-'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.googleusercontent.apps.android_account_id'  in build.gradle with my account id

And also I have done the google cloud consent screen part, android and ios client id creation.

I do not know what could be the problem... My guess is something to do with the supabase configuration or  appAuthRedirectScheme but not the typical problem as I have already tried what people usually say...

Thanks to whoever takes some time to help me!

Comment: Any luck ? How did you end up implementing Google log in ? I tried the one tap flutter lib and had issues.